# join three objects on remote action

Tags: custom-object, query, array

In regards to reports the regular ones are not working for what we are trying to achieve we have 5 objects that are related in someway or another but not specifically one to another, having an scenario like this

```
Object 1 has reference to 2 and 3
Object 2
Object 3
Object 4 has reference to 2
Object 5 has reference to 2
```

So in my initial query I can grab the needed info from Object 1, 2, 3 however since there is no connection from object 1,2 or 3 to objects 4 or 5 then I can't add them in the query or I don't know how to, now my questions is that once I pull the records I can run through them all and pull the needed related 4 and 5 object but how can I add that as part of the response, is there a way to create an array of objects or can I access objects 4,5 from the same query?

```
global static Object1__c[] getReport(Integer page, Id program){
    Object1__c[] rows = [
        select 
        Id,
        Name,
        /*Object2__r relations*/
        o1.Object2__c,
        o1.Object2__r.Name,
        o1.Object2__r.Id,
        /*Object2__r relations ends*/
        /*Object3__r relations*/
        o1.Object3__c,
        o1.Object3__r.Name,
        o1.Object3__r.Id,
        /*Object3__r relations end*/
        from Object1__c o1
        where
        o1.Program__c = :program
        limit 30
    ];
    if(rows.size() > 0){
        for(Object1__c o1:rows){
            /*query here the other two objects*/
            Object4__c[] o4 = [
                select 
                Id,
                Name
                from
                Object4__c
                where
                Object1__c = :o1.Object2__r.Id
            ];
            Object5__c[] o5 = [
                select 
                Id,
                Name
                from
                Object5__c
                where
                Object2__c = :o1.Object2__r.Id
            ];
            /* how do I add o4 and o5 to the o1 row? */
        }
    }
    return rows;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write some code based on this [Mock.makeRelationship](https://gist.github.com/afawcett/8dbfc0e1d8c43c982881#file-mock-cls-L66) code to wire up the disconnected objects after they are queried. Messy enough though as you have a total of 5 related objects. (Do read the whole blog post that this comes from too - [Mocking SOQL sub-select query results](http://andyinthecloud.com/2014/12/03/mocking-soql-sub-select-query-results/) by Andrew Fawcett)

An alternative is to create a simple Apex class to hold the parent-child relationships:

```
public class Relationship {
    public Object[] sob {get; private set;}
    public Relationship[] children {get; private set;}
    public Relationship(SObject sob) {
        this.sob = sob;
        this.children = new Relationship[] {};
    }
}
```

and accept that the serialised form will be changed:

```
[
    {
        "sob": ...,
        "children": [
            {
                "sob": ...,
                "children": [
                   ...
                ]
            },
            ...
        ]
    },
    ...
]
```

Note that you should [bulkify](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices) your Object 4 and Object 5 queries too.

Comment: This Mock.makeRelationship is interesting. But I am not quite sure about what is the difference between this and regular child subqueries?

Comment: @LanceShi Its using the fact that JSON deserialize can handle deep graphs of related objects and correctly set the __r fields in the process, where as SOQL is more limited e.g. one level of children only. More devious than elegant though.

Answer (score 1):

Tlacaelel, using **Object 1** as the focal point, you can execute a single SOQL statement and pull data from all 5 objects. The trick to doing this is to leverage [child subqueries](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm) in the statement.

For example, let's use the following analogies to your question:

- **Object 1** = `OpportunityContactRole` has references to `Opportunity` and `Contact` through `OpportunityContactRole.OpportunityId` and `OpportunityContactRole.ContactId`
- **Object 2** = `Opportunity`
- **Object 3** = `Contact`
- **Object 4** = `Task` has reference to `Contact` thorugh `Task.WhoId`
- **Object 5** = `Note` has reference to `Contact` through `Note.ParentId`

Below is the Apex code which shows the single SOQL statement which pulls data from *all five (5) objects*.

```
// Get a list of all matching contacts, based on query criteria 
// established at the Opportunity Contact Role level
List<Contact> matchingContacts = [
    SELECT Id, Name,
        (
            SELECT Id,
                OpportunityId,
                Opportunity.Name
            FROM OpportunityContactRoles
        ),
        (
            SELECT Id, Subject
            FROM Tasks
        ),
        (
            SELECT Id, Title
            FROM Notes
        )
    FROM Contact
    WHERE Id IN (
        SELECT ContactId
        FROM OpportunityContactRole
        WHERE CreatedDate = THIS_WEEK
    )
];

// Go through all of the contacts, and systematically display the names
// of all related opportunities, the subjects of all related tasks, and
// the titles of all related notes.
for (Contact eachContact : matchingContacts) {

    // Display the names of all related opportunities
    for (OpportunityContactRole eachRole : eachContact.OpportunityContactRoles)
        System.debug(eachRole.Opportunity.Name);

    // Display the subjects of all related tasks
    for (Task eachTask : eachContact.Tasks)
        System.debug(eachTask.Subject);

    // Display the titles of all related notes
    for (Note eachNote : eachContact.Notes)
        System.debug(eachNote.Title);
}
```

You can see that the `WHERE` clause is applied at the `OpportunityContactRole` (i.e., **Object 1**) level, which is what you implied as a requirement in your question.

Comment: This is a good thought and these sort of re-arrangements are worth looking into. But in this case, I don't think it works. For example, if there are no Contact rows present your query will return no results. In the query in the question, if there are no Object 3 rows present, Object 1 rows can still be returned. That is they are not equivalent queries.

Comment: I am getting a "Didn't understand relationship" I don't think this works or maybe I am writing it wrong, for the moment I think I will go with the @KeithC Object[] approach and then I will further try your query